# When can I buy certain items?

Tags: path-of-exile

I'm level 30 and want to buy Brass Maul, which requires only requires level 27. However, I am unable to find it on the shop.

What determines which items are sold?

When will I be able to buy Brass Maul? (for upgrading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more likely that you will be able to find one off mobs that are of that level or higher. So for an ilevel 27 item you would need to kill a normal mob that is 27, a blue mob that is 26 or a rare mob that is 25. Blue and rares are bumped up +1 and +2 respectively from their level.

Usually I just go into the right act and difficulty and blow through a bunch of mobs. Vendors are only refreshed I believe on a level up so if it's not in any of the vendors then I would suggest just farming.

Comment: I have indeed found this, apparently I am massively overleveled.